# GUI with Z-Depth in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'd like create an interface that has two sliding panels (similar to an elevator doors, but in vertical way ) that at click on a button show contents behind them.

My first idea was to create a structure like this:

```
Window (NSWindow)
|----ContentView (NSView)
     |-------OpenDoor (NSButton)
     |-------TopDoor (NSView)
     |-------BottomDoor (NSView)
     |-------Content (NsView)
                    |------Here some contents ()
```

Pushing OpenDoor button,the Top and Bottom door must move up/down, showing the content behind them. 
I'm not sure that this is the better way to do something like that. Is the CALayer way the most indicated  solution for a GUI with this behavior ? or what else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, request layers on the door components, then animate `position.y`.

Although it's somewhat counterintuitive, it's easier to set the view's frame to the ending frame, then build the animation based on that position.

`CABasicAnimation` should easily cover you here.

Comment: thank you Nate. So you suggest to animate the frame property of a View with CABasicAnimation ?

Comment: Not quite, set the frame of the view to above/below, then animate `position.y` (yes, you can do that). You could do it with the frame, but the only thing changing the the Y position, so it seems a little silly. This also allows you to resize the window during the transition and have the horizontal resizing work as expected.